# react native - Image not showing on custom callout in mapview?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I have a map screen with markers, I try to add image to the callout and I use same method of `<image source = .. />`  as I did in other place that works, but on the map it wont show me the picture.

```
 {
        this.state.markers.map(marker => (
          
          <MapView.Marker
            key={marker.id}
            coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}>
              <MapView.Callout>
                <View>
                      <View>
                        {marker.imageUri && <Image source = {{uri: marker.imageUri}}
                        style = {{ width: '90%', height: 100, justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, alignContent: 'center', resizeMode: 'stretch'}}
                      />  }        
                      </View>
                    <Text>Lat: {marker.latitude}, Lon: {marker.longitude}</Text>
                    <Text>{marker.email}</Text>
                </View>
              </MapView.Callout>         
          </MapView.Marker>
        ))
      }
```

it gives me a blank view instead of the image.
Have I done any mistake?

Answer (score 5):

Use Image inside Text component,It is strange but it works :)

```js
<Text> <Image style={{ height: 100, width:100 }} source={{ ... }} resizeMode="cover" /> </Text>
```

Comment: Does it really work, have you tried it?

Comment: yes,i tried it and its working fine

Comment: It doesn't make sense but it actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using a webView for android: `const Img = isAndroid ? WebView: Image; return <Img source={{uri: someUri}} />`

Answer (score -1):

[Doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webview/)

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
```

If `const isAndroid = Platform.OS === 'android';` is true render a WebView... if not render a Image.

Comment: Could you please add the code in a code brackets for a better reading experience. Welcome to SO :)